# Google Spreadsheets: How to create an anchor to a row inside the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets

is there a way in google spreadsheet to create an anchor text in order to jump from one row to another with a simple click without page reloading?
I'm not able to find a way...
Thank you

Comment: The only way I know it to attach a Script to an image, it's really unpractical tough, as you need to create a new script for each line, like so: `function goTo(){
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(55, 1).activate();
}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I seem to have found a solution:

- Select the Set of Cells you want to link to (Left-click + Drag)
- Right-Click the Selected Cells ==> Select "Get link to this range"
- The Sheet Link will now be copied to your clipboard and can now be accessed by anybody who has access to the sheet.